# find the largest number that can't be written as $2008x+2009y+2010 z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

> Find the largest number that can't be written as $2008x+2009y+2010 z$, in the following cases:

1. $x,y,z$ are all positive integers.
2. $x,y,z$ are all nonnegative integers.

> 

For integers $a_1,\cdots, a_n,$ let $N_{a_1,\cdots, a_n}$ denote the set of all nonnegative linear combinations of $a$ and $b$ (i.e. all integers $\sum_{i=1}^n k_i a_i, \,\forall 1\leq i\leq n, k_i\ge 0$). Define $P_{a_1,\cdots, a_n}$ to be the set of all positive linear combinations of the $a_i$'s.
I know that if $a,b$ are positive integers, the largest positive multiple of $d := \gcd(a,b)$ that is not in $N_{a,b}$ is $\dfrac{ab}d-a-b.$ Then the largest positive multiple of $\gcd(a,b)$ that is not in $P_{a,b}$ is $\dfrac{ab}d.$ Indeed, from any number exceeding $\dfrac{ab}d$ we can subtract $a$ and $b$ to get a number exceeding $\dfrac{ab}d-a-b \ge \dfrac{ab}d-a-b$, and from above we know this number must be in $N_{a,b}$. Also, if $ab/d = ax+by$ for positive integers x and y, then $ab/d -ax = by \Rightarrow a/d (b/d-x) = b/d y,$ so $a/d | y\Rightarrow y\ge a/d$ and $b/d | (b/d - x)\Rightarrow b/d - x \ge b/d$. The latter inequality is a contradiction as $x > 0.$ For the particular problem, we know $1004\cdot 1005/2 - 1004 - 1005)$ is the largest even integer that is not in $N_{2008,2010}.$ But I'm not sure what the largest integer that is not in $N_{2008,2009,2010}$ (is it just $2009 + 1004\cdot 1005/2 - 1004 - 1005$?).  I think the largest integer that is not in $P_{2008, 2009,2010}$ might be larger than the latter integer.

> Edit: following a similar approach to @ThomasAndrews' answer, I think the answer to the first question is $C := 2008\cdot 1007+2.$ First I claim that $C$ cannot be achieved. Indeed, if this were the case then we could write $2008a+b+c =C$ for some $a > b > c > 0.$ Then note that $b+c\leq 2a-3.$ So $a\leq 1006$ implies $b+c\leq 2009$ and so $2008 a + b+c < 2008\cdot 1006 + 2010 = C.$ Hence we must have $a=1007$ and that is clearly impossible since $b+c > 3$ implies $2008a+b+c > C.$ Next I claim that any number that's at least $C + 1$ can be expressed in the desired form. To see why, take such a number $z.$ Then if $C+1 \leq z\leq 2008\cdot 1008 - 1,$ let $k= z-(C+1)$ so that $0\leq k \leq 2004.$ Note that we just need $b+c = k+3$ to have $2008\cdot 1007 + b+c = z.$ If $0\leq k\leq 1004,$ let $a=1007, b=k+2, c=1.$ If $1005\leq k\leq 2004,$ then let $a=1007, b=1006, c=k-1004.$ Now suppose $2008 x \leq z \leq 2008(x+1)-1$ for some $x\ge 1008.$ If $z = 2008 x + i$ for some $0\leq i\leq 2,$ let $a=x-1, b=1006, c=1002 + i$. If $z =2008x+i$ for some $3\leq i\leq 1008,$ let $a=x, b=i-1, c=1$. Finally if $z=2008x+i$ for some $1009\leq i\leq 2007,$ then let $a=x, b = 1007, c=i-1007.$

Comment: first solve    for $4x+5y+6z$     and maybe  $8x+9y+10z$

Comment: Write it as $2008a+b+c$ where $a=x+y+z, b=y+z, c=z.$ Then your conditions is $a>b>c>0$ in the first case or $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$ in the second case.

Comment: But the second case is the easier case to work in.

Comment: A number $N$ can be written that way for positive $x,y,z$ if and only if $N-6027$ can be for nonnegative $x,y,z$.

Comment: yeah, for even $M,$ and non-negative $x,y,z$ in $Mx+(M+1)y + (M+2) z,$  clear what happens

Comment: Isn't this just the  Frobenius  coin problem?

Comment: @fleablood it's a fairly special case of that general problem, so I figured there would be a significantly easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as $2008a+b+c$ where $a=x+y+z, b=y+z, c=z.$ Then your condition is $a>b>c>0$ in the first case or $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$ in the second case.

We'll take the second case, because it is easier.

If $a\leq1003,$ then $b+c\leq 2a\leq 2006 ,$ so we can never get $2008a+2007.$

On the other hand, if $a\geq 1004,$ for any $r=0,1,2,\dots,2007,$ we can find $c\leq b\leq a$ such that $r=b+c.$

So this means the largest number we can't reach is $2008\cdot 1003+2007=2008\cdot 1004-1.$

You can deduce the answer for the first case from the second case.

The same works for $mx +(m+1)y+(m+2)z$ for any $m.$ For $m$ even, you get $m^2/2-1$ is not a number of this form. For $m$ odd, a little care is required. $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}-1?$

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you confirm whether you can understand what I've been trying to say in my question? For some reason it seems some people can't understand my question (even though I'm pretty sure I made correct, clear claims).

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Frobenius Coin Problem**.

The specific question of largest number not represented by $2008x + 2009y + 2010z$ is a special case of finding the Frobenius number for elements that form an arithmetic sequence.

A simple closed form formula exists for the Frobenius number of a set of integers in an arithmetic sequence. Given integers $a, d, w$ with $\gcd(a, d) = 1$, the Frobenius number for the set is:

$$
{\displaystyle g(a,a+d,a+2d,\dots ,a+wd)=\left(\left\lfloor {\frac {a-2}{w}}\right\rfloor \right)a+d(a-1)}
$$

For the example problem, $a = 2008, d = 1, w = 2$.

$$
\begin{align}
g(2008, 2009, 2010) & = \left(\left\lfloor {\frac {2008-2}{2}}\right\rfloor \right)2008+(1)(2008-1) \\
& = 1003 \times 2008 + 2007 \\
& = 2016031
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks. But what if $x,y,z$ MUST be positive integers?

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow what you are saying even from the start, so this is an alternative approach that I hope will help.

For $b=2008$, it is
$$bx + (b+1)y + (b+2)z = n$$
$$bx + (y+z)b + y + 2z = n$$

The $bx$ term makes it clear that all multiples of $b$ can be constructed by choosing $y=z=0$.

All $n \equiv 1 \pmod b$ can be constructed except $n=1$ by letting $y=1, z=0$.

All $n \equiv 2 \pmod b$ can be constructed except $n=2$ by letting $y=0, z=1$.

All $n \equiv 3 \pmod b$ can be constructed except $n=3, n=b+3$ by letting $y=1, z=1$.

All $n \equiv 4 \pmod b$ can be constructed except $n=4, n=b+4$ by letting $y=0, z=2$.

Etc.

All $n \equiv r \pmod b$ can be constructed except $n=kb+r, k < y+z$ by letting $y=(r \bmod 2), z=\lfloor r/2 \rfloor$.

So the largest will come from choosing $r=b-1, k=y+z-1$.

Comment: what about what I'm saying do you not understand? I thought my approach was quite clear.